# Connection refused on locahost after importing database?

Tags: database, import, phpmyadmin

I'm using Wordpress Instant for my development environment. It's a portable dev environment that allows me to run a local wp install off a usb, so it's portable and I can take it from one computer to the next in a nice self contained fashion.

Previously I was using MAMP.

The initial wp install went fine, I imported my theme and plugins, and updated everything that needed updating.

I created a new database inside phpadmin, and then imported the old database into it. I set the wp-config file to have the right database name, username, and password etc. But when I try to open up the front page or wp-login of the website I get a connection refused error.

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer. I needed to update my siteurl and home in the database: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27966733/can-not-connect-to-wordpress-in-localhost-get-http-localhost-neterr-connec

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing a similar issue which was mainly caused by not looking through my entire config file and the fact that I'm a Wordpress newby.

I needed to restart apache using `sudo apachectl restart` and then I found that `$table_prefix` was set to 'wp_' by default in my wp-config.php file. By updating the field it loaded fine. You could also rename your table to add the prefix, though this could lead to other issues if you were expecting the name to not have it.